# WPF - inherit from System.Windows.Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008

I would like to have my own application class that inherits from System.Windows.Application. The problem is that in the Application.xaml file, I have to declare the app like this :

```
    <src:MyBaseApplication x:Class="MyApplication"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:MyApplication;assembly=WpfTestApplication"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="FPrincipal.xaml">    
    <Application.Resources>
        
    </Application.Resources>
</src:MyBaseApplication>
```

It works great at runtime, but when I edit the project properties, I receive the following error message by the project properties editor of Visual Studio :

> An error occurred trying to load the application definition file for this project.  The file '[...]\Application.xaml' could not be parsed.  Please edit the file in the XAML editor to fix the error.
> Could not find the expected root element "Application" in the application definition file.

The project is a VB.NET project. Somebody have a workaround? I want to keep the application.xaml file.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I just tried it and there is no error, I was able to derive from System.Windows.Application, and then use it in my App.Xaml, everything works as it should, no view complains about anything.

Comment: @adminSoftDK: did you try it with VS2008?

Comment: @DanielLeiszen sorry, I did not notice that. No I tried it in VS2015

Comment: Yes, I don't even have VS2008 on my computer. I am not sure this question is still relevant, and I suspect this bounty is a mistake....

Comment: @adminSoftDK I've tried it in VS 2015 and it doesn't work. Did you try with VB.NET? VB.NET appears to add a compiler-generated class with WPF extensions.

Comment: @DanielLeiszen I just created a clean solution in VS 2015 with two VB.NET projects -- a class library with a class inheriting from `System.Windows.Application`, and a WPF application with a reference to the class library. The issue still exists.

Comment: I updated my answer with the code and steps that work for me on VS2013. Please check and mark as answer if helps. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried it with Visual Studio 2013 but I did not experience any problem. So, it should be VS 2008 specific. Did you try to reorganize your application class into a separate class library? Maybe it is a locking issue.

**UPDATE**

The steps I did in VB.NET VS2013 in order to make it happen:

1. Create the custom application class. I created it in the same assembly. My assembly name was: WPFVBTest

> ```
> Public Class CustomApplication
>   Inherits System.Windows.Application
>
> End Class
> ```

2. Modify the Application.xaml. Add the namespace reference and change the root container to the custom application class.

> ```
>   <self:CustomApplication x:Class="Application"
>         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>       xmlns:self="clr-namespace:WPFVBTest"
>         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
>     </self:CustomApplication>
> ```

3. Modify the code behind file: Application.xaml.vb to inherit from the CustomApplication class

> ```
> Class Application
>   Inherits CustomApplication
>
> End Class
> ```

4. Build the application. One error should occur indicating that MyWpfExtension.vb is not in sync with the application class name. This is a generated class, but not regenerated at every build. I know its cheating, but this was the only way I could manage it. So I modified it manually:

> ```
> Partial Class Application
>   Inherits CustomApplication
> ```

This way the application builds and runs without a problem. I hope it helps you to solve your error.

Comment: I am still having a problem in VS 2015. For my scenario (I set the bounty), the `MyBaseApplication` class exists in a class library. What do you mean by a locking issue?

Comment: What I can think of, that VS cannot load the custom application class because it is in use. Maybe VS itself is using it, or some other app. Does it happen when you right click on the project and try to open Properties? Do you use any other tool in VS that can use the assembly? Reflector.NET or some other 3rd party tool?

Comment: Just to confirm - are you doing this with VB.NET?

Comment: Please, see the updated answer. I included the VB.NET code I used.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not going to be a popular answer, but... why don't you just upgrade to Visual Studio 2015? Its free!

Hell, they announced VS 2017 just yesterday; also free.

Comment: I am using VS 2015 and it still doesn't work. Are you using C# or VB.NET?

Answer (score -1):

Should it say < src:MyBaseApplication.Resources > ?

Comment: Well you could, but since you are inheriting from Application, you can also use Application.Resources...

Answer (score -1):

Applications usually points to a Window and tries to get this information from the xaml file; but you have a reference in your xaml file that Visual Studio cannot determine..

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:MyApplication;assembly=WpfTestApplication"
```

So VS cannot parse your xaml file, and thus gives that error...

My suggestion: override the Window, or use extensions on Application, like so :

```
public static class ApplicationExtensions
{
    public static string GetAwesomeName(this Application)
    {
        return "I am an awesome application";
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Application.Current.GetAwesomeName();
```

Comment: You miss something. The error message specify that the Application tag is missing. It's true because the root tag is src:MyBaseApplication. VisualStudio should be wise enough to find the root tag with a different name. I already know that I can subclass the application in C#, but doing this we'll lose the .xaml file associated with the application.

Comment: Have you considered slicing up those pieces of xaml into a ResourceDictionary and include that in the Resources of your Application?