# In WPF force App to inherit from a class defferent from System.Windows.Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to change App's base class to inherits from my own class in a class library.
It is already like this:
`public partial class App : System.Windows.Application`.
Now I want to change it to
`public partial class App : MainModule.App`
which `MainModule.App` is in a class library. When I change it, `App.g.i.cs` dosn't let me because it inherits from `System.Windows.Application` . When I change `App.g.i.cs` after compiling it goes back to its default: `System.Windows.Application`. Is there any way to force Ap`enter code here`p class to inherit from my class. Not that `MainModule.App` inherits from `System.Windows.Application`.

Comment: Can you explain, what goal you want to achieve? Maybe some other solutions will suit for you then

Comment: I want to separate my UI from my business. There are some tasks which must be done in App class. These tasks are located in a DLL which has not been referenced by my Application file. So that I moved App class to a class library which has access to that DLL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it. I did 2 works:
1- I changed `MainModule.App` to `MainModule.MyApp`.
2- I changed App.xaml to:

```
<mainModule:MyApp x:Class="FrontOffice.XBAP.App"
...
xmlns:mainModule="clr-namespace:MainModule;assembly=MainModule">
```

It's now working.

Comment: The reason for this is the "partial" within the class name. The actual class the compiler wants to process is a combination of the XAML part (which is actually automatically generated into the `App.g.i.cs` file) and the code behind part. Both partial classes must inherit from the same base class or the compiler cannot combine them into a single class.

Comment: Once you do this, you [cannot open the project property pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940644/wpf-inherit-from-system-windows-application).